# Convert *.XLSX to .XLS using apache poi

Tags: java, apache-poi, converters, xls, xlsx

I have a requirement to convert *.xlsx (just single sheet with image) to *.xls. And then insert that sheet into another workbook. Any idea?

I use

- apache poi 3.9,
- poi-ooxml-3.8,
- poi-ooxml-schemas-3.9.jar,
- dom4j-1.6.jar,
- xmlbeans-2.6.0.jar,
- nextreports-engine-6.2.jar.

And I this code (it doesn't work):

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.TreeSet;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPatriarch;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPicture;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFPictureData;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFShape;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.hssf.usermodel.HSSFWorkbook;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Cell;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CellStyle;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.ClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.CreationHelper;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.DataFormat;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Drawing;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Font;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Footer;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Header;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Name;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.PrintSetup;
import org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Sheet;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellRangeAddress;
import org.apache.poi.ss.util.CellReference;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFCell;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFClientAnchor;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFDrawing;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFName;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPicture;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFPictureData;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFRow;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFShape;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFSheet;
import org.apache.poi.xssf.usermodel.XSSFWorkbook;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.CTMarker;
import org.openxmlformats.schemas.drawingml.x2006.spreadsheetDrawing.CTTwoCellAnchor;
import ro.nextreports.engine.exporter.util.CellRangeAddressWrapper;
public class CreateExcelFile {
@SuppressWarnings("unused")
private static class FormulaInfo {
private String sheetName;
private Integer rowIndex;
private Integer cellIndex;
private String formula;
private FormulaInfo(String sheetName, Integer rowIndex, Integer cellIndex, String formula) {
this.sheetName = sheetName;
this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
this.cellIndex = cellIndex;
this.formula = formula;
}
public String getSheetName() {
return sheetName;
}

public void setSheetName(String sheetName) {
this.sheetName = sheetName;
}

public Integer getRowIndex() {
return rowIndex;
}

public void setRowIndex(Integer rowIndex) {
this.rowIndex = rowIndex;
}

public Integer getCellIndex() {
return cellIndex;
}

public void setCellIndex(Integer cellIndex) {
this.cellIndex = cellIndex;
}

public String getFormula() {
return formula;
}

public void setFormula(String formula) {
this.formula = formula;
}
}

static List<FormulaInfo> formulaInfoList = new ArrayList<FormulaInfo>();

public static void refreshFormula(HSSFWorkbook workbook) {
for (FormulaInfo formulaInfo : formulaInfoList) {
workbook.getSheet(formulaInfo.getSheetName()).getRow(formulaInfo.getRowIndex())
.getCell(formulaInfo.getCellIndex()).setCellFormula(formulaInfo.getFormula());
}
formulaInfoList.removeAll(formulaInfoList);
}

//Main method
public static void main(String[] args){
try {
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("temp.xlsx");
XSSFWorkbook wbIn = new XSSFWorkbook(fis);
HSSFWorkbook wbOut = convertWorkbookXSSFToHSSF(wbIn);
FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("temp.xls");
wbOut.write(fos);
fos.close();
} catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(CreateExcelFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
} catch (IOException ex) {
Logger.getLogger(CreateExcelFile.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
}
public static HSSFWorkbook convertWorkbookXSSFToHSSF(XSSFWorkbook source) {
HSSFWorkbook retVal = new HSSFWorkbook();

for (int i = 0; i < source.getNumberOfSheets(); i++) {

XSSFSheet xssfsheet = source.getSheetAt(i);
HSSFSheet hssfSheet = retVal.createSheet(xssfsheet.getSheetName());

copySheetSettings(hssfSheet, xssfsheet);
copySheet(xssfsheet, hssfSheet);
copyPictures(hssfSheet, xssfsheet);
}

refreshFormula(retVal);

return retVal;
}

private static void copySheet(XSSFSheet source, HSSFSheet destination) {
copySheet(source, destination, true);
}

/**
* @param destination
*            the sheet to create from the copy.
* @param the
*            sheet to copy.
* @param copyStyle
*            true copy the style.
*/
private static void copySheet(XSSFSheet source, HSSFSheet destination, boolean copyStyle) {
int maxColumnNum = 0;
List<CellStyle> styleMap2 = (copyStyle) ? new ArrayList<CellStyle>() : null;
for (int i = source.getFirstRowNum(); i <= source.getLastRowNum(); i++) {
XSSFRow srcRow = source.getRow(i);
HSSFRow destRow = destination.createRow(i);
if (srcRow != null) {
// copyRow(source, destination, srcRow, destRow, styleMap);
copyRow(source, destination, srcRow, destRow, styleMap2);
if (srcRow.getLastCellNum() > maxColumnNum) {
maxColumnNum = srcRow.getLastCellNum();
}
}
}
for (int i = 0; i <= maxColumnNum; i++) {
destination.setColumnWidth(i, source.getColumnWidth(i));
}
}

/**
* @param srcSheet
*            the sheet to copy.
* @param destSheet
*            the sheet to create.
* @param srcRow
*            the row to copy.
* @param destRow
*            the row to create.
* @param styleMap
*            -
*/
private static void copyRow(XSSFSheet srcSheet, HSSFSheet destSheet, XSSFRow srcRow, HSSFRow destRow,
// Map<Integer, HSSFCellStyle> styleMap) {
List<CellStyle> styleMap) {
// manage a list of merged zone in order to not insert two times a
// merged zone
Set<CellRangeAddressWrapper> mergedRegions = new TreeSet<CellRangeAddressWrapper>();
destRow.setHeight(srcRow.getHeight());
// pour chaque row
// for (int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum(); j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum();
// j++) {
int j = srcRow.getFirstCellNum();
if (j < 0) {
j = 0;
}
for (; j <= srcRow.getLastCellNum(); j++) {
XSSFCell oldCell = srcRow.getCell(j); // ancienne cell
HSSFCell newCell = destRow.getCell(j); // new cell
if (oldCell != null) {
if (newCell == null) {
newCell = destRow.createCell(j);
}
// copy chaque cell
copyCell(oldCell, newCell, styleMap);
// copy les informations de fusion entre les cellules
// System.out.println("row num: " + srcRow.getRowNum() +
// " , col: " + (short)oldCell.getColumnIndex());
CellRangeAddress mergedRegion = getMergedRegion(srcSheet, srcRow.getRowNum(),
    (short) oldCell.getColumnIndex());

if (mergedRegion != null) {
// System.out.println("Selected merged region: " +
// mergedRegion.toString());
CellRangeAddress newMergedRegion = new CellRangeAddress(mergedRegion.getFirstRow(),
        mergedRegion.getLastRow(), mergedRegion.getFirstColumn(), mergedRegion.getLastColumn());
// System.out.println("New merged region: " +
// newMergedRegion.toString());
CellRangeAddressWrapper wrapper = new CellRangeAddressWrapper(newMergedRegion);
if (isNewMergedRegion(wrapper, mergedRegions)) {
    mergedRegions.add(wrapper);
    destSheet.addMergedRegion(wrapper.range);
}
}
}
}

}

/**
* Récupère les informations de fusion des cellules dans la sheet source
* pour les appliquer à la sheet destination... Récupère toutes les zones
* merged dans la sheet source et regarde pour chacune d'elle si elle se
* trouve dans la current row que nous traitons. Si oui, retourne l'objet
* CellRangeAddress.
* 
* @param sheet
*            the sheet containing the data.
* @param rowNum
*            the num of the row to copy.
* @param cellNum
*            the num of the cell to copy.
* @return the CellRangeAddress created.
*/
public static CellRangeAddress getMergedRegion(XSSFSheet sheet, int rowNum, short cellNum) {
for (int i = 0; i < sheet.getNumMergedRegions(); i++) {
CellRangeAddress merged = sheet.getMergedRegion(i);
if (merged.isInRange(rowNum, cellNum)) {
return merged;
}
}
return null;
}

/**
* Check that the merged region has been created in the destination sheet.
* 
* @param newMergedRegion
*            the merged region to copy or not in the destination sheet.
* @param mergedRegions
*            the list containing all the merged region.
* @return true if the merged region is already in the list or not.
*/
private static boolean isNewMergedRegion(CellRangeAddressWrapper newMergedRegion,
Set<CellRangeAddressWrapper> mergedRegions) {
return !mergedRegions.contains(newMergedRegion);
}

private static void copyPictures(Sheet newSheet, Sheet sheet) {
Drawing drawingOld = sheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
Drawing drawingNew = newSheet.createDrawingPatriarch();
CreationHelper helper = newSheet.getWorkbook().getCreationHelper();

// if (drawingNew instanceof HSSFPatriarch) {
        if (drawingOld instanceof HSSFPatriarch) {
            List<HSSFShape> shapes = ((HSSFPatriarch) drawingOld).getChildren();
            for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
                System.out.println(shapes.size());
                if (shapes.get(i) instanceof HSSFPicture) {
                    HSSFPicture pic = (HSSFPicture) shapes.get(i);
                    HSSFPictureData picdata = pic.getPictureData();
                   int pictureIndex = newSheet.getWorkbook().addPicture(picdata.getData(), picdata.getFormat());
                    ClientAnchor anchor = null;
                    if (pic.getAnchor() != null) {
                        anchor = helper.createClientAnchor();
                       anchor.setDx1(((HSSFClientAnchor) pic.getAnchor()).getDx1());
                        anchor.setDx2(((HSSFClientAnchor) pic.getAnchor()).getDx2());
                        anchor.setDy1(((HSSFClientAnchor) pic.getAnchor()).getDy1());
                       anchor.setDy2(((HSSFClientAnchor) pic.getAnchor()).getDy2());
                        anchor.setCol1(((HSSFClientAnchor) pic.getAnchor()).getCol1());
                        anchor.setCol2(((HSSFClientAnchor) pic.getAnchor()).getCol2());
                        anchor.setRow1(((HSSFClientAnchor) pic.getAnchor()).getRow1());
                        anchor.setRow2(((HSSFClientAnchor) pic.getAnchor()).getRow2());
                        anchor.setAnchorType(((HSSFClientAnchor) pic.getAnchor()).getAnchorType());
                    }
                    drawingNew.createPicture(anchor, pictureIndex);
                }
            }
        } else {
if (drawingNew instanceof XSSFDrawing) {
List<XSSFShape> shapes = ((XSSFDrawing) drawingOld).getShapes();
for (int i = 0; i < shapes.size(); i++) {
if (shapes.get(i) instanceof XSSFPicture) {
    XSSFPicture pic = (XSSFPicture) shapes.get(i);
    XSSFPictureData picdata = pic.getPictureData();
    int pictureIndex = newSheet.getWorkbook().addPicture(picdata.getData(),picdata.getPictureType());
    XSSFClientAnchor anchor = null;
    CTTwoCellAnchor oldAnchor = ((XSSFDrawing) drawingOld).getCTDrawing().getTwoCellAnchorArray(i);
    if (oldAnchor != null) {
        anchor = (XSSFClientAnchor) helper.createClientAnchor();
        CTMarker markerFrom = oldAnchor.getFrom();
        CTMarker markerTo = oldAnchor.getTo();
        anchor.setDx1((int) markerFrom.getColOff());
        anchor.setDx2((int) markerTo.getColOff());
        anchor.setDy1((int) markerFrom.getRowOff());
        anchor.setDy2((int) markerTo.getRowOff());
        anchor.setCol1(markerFrom.getCol());
        anchor.setCol2(markerTo.getCol());
        anchor.setRow1(markerFrom.getRow());
        anchor.setRow2(markerTo.getRow());
    }
    drawingNew.createPicture(anchor, pictureIndex);
}
}
//            }
}
}

private static void copyCell(Cell oldCell, Cell newCell, List<CellStyle> styleList) {
if (styleList != null) {
if (oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook() == newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook()) {
newCell.setCellStyle(oldCell.getCellStyle());
} else {
DataFormat newDataFormat = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createDataFormat();

CellStyle newCellStyle = getSameCellStyle(oldCell, newCell, styleList);
if (newCellStyle == null) {
// Create a new cell style
Font oldFont = oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getFontAt(oldCell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex());
// Find a existing font corresponding to avoid to create a
// new one
Font newFont = newCell
        .getSheet()
        .getWorkbook()
        .findFont(oldFont.getBoldweight(), oldFont.getColor(), oldFont.getFontHeight(),
                oldFont.getFontName(), oldFont.getItalic(), oldFont.getStrikeout(),
                oldFont.getTypeOffset(), oldFont.getUnderline());
if (newFont == null) {
    newFont = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createFont();
    newFont.setBoldweight(oldFont.getBoldweight());
    newFont.setColor(oldFont.getColor());
    newFont.setFontHeight(oldFont.getFontHeight());
    newFont.setFontName(oldFont.getFontName());
    newFont.setItalic(oldFont.getItalic());
    newFont.setStrikeout(oldFont.getStrikeout());
    newFont.setTypeOffset(oldFont.getTypeOffset());
    newFont.setUnderline(oldFont.getUnderline());
    newFont.setCharSet(oldFont.getCharSet());
}

short newFormat = newDataFormat.getFormat(oldCell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString());
newCellStyle = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().createCellStyle();
newCellStyle.setFont(newFont);
newCellStyle.setDataFormat(newFormat);

newCellStyle.setAlignment(oldCell.getCellStyle().getAlignment());
newCellStyle.setHidden(oldCell.getCellStyle().getHidden());
newCellStyle.setLocked(oldCell.getCellStyle().getLocked());
newCellStyle.setWrapText(oldCell.getCellStyle().getWrapText());
newCellStyle.setBorderBottom(oldCell.getCellStyle().getBorderBottom());
newCellStyle.setBorderLeft(oldCell.getCellStyle().getBorderLeft());
newCellStyle.setBorderRight(oldCell.getCellStyle().getBorderRight());
newCellStyle.setBorderTop(oldCell.getCellStyle().getBorderTop());
newCellStyle.setBottomBorderColor(oldCell.getCellStyle().getBottomBorderColor());
newCellStyle.setFillBackgroundColor(oldCell.getCellStyle().getFillBackgroundColor());
newCellStyle.setFillForegroundColor(oldCell.getCellStyle().getFillForegroundColor());
newCellStyle.setFillPattern(oldCell.getCellStyle().getFillPattern());
newCellStyle.setIndention(oldCell.getCellStyle().getIndention());
newCellStyle.setLeftBorderColor(oldCell.getCellStyle().getLeftBorderColor());
newCellStyle.setRightBorderColor(oldCell.getCellStyle().getRightBorderColor());
newCellStyle.setRotation(oldCell.getCellStyle().getRotation());
newCellStyle.setTopBorderColor(oldCell.getCellStyle().getTopBorderColor());
newCellStyle.setVerticalAlignment(oldCell.getCellStyle().getVerticalAlignment());

styleList.add(newCellStyle);
}
newCell.setCellStyle(newCellStyle);
}
}
switch (oldCell.getCellType()) {
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getStringCellValue());
break;
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:
newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getNumericCellValue());
break;
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK:
newCell.setCellType(Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK);
break;
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_BOOLEAN:
newCell.setCellValue(oldCell.getBooleanCellValue());
break;
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_ERROR:
newCell.setCellErrorValue(oldCell.getErrorCellValue());
break;
case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:
newCell.setCellFormula(oldCell.getCellFormula());
formulaInfoList.add(new FormulaInfo(oldCell.getSheet().getSheetName(), oldCell.getRowIndex(), oldCell
.getColumnIndex(), oldCell.getCellFormula()));
break;
default:
break;
}
}

private static CellStyle getSameCellStyle(Cell oldCell, Cell newCell, List<CellStyle> styleList) {
CellStyle styleToFind = oldCell.getCellStyle();
CellStyle currentCellStyle = null;
CellStyle returnCellStyle = null;
Iterator<CellStyle> iterator = styleList.iterator();
Font oldFont = null;
Font newFont = null;
while (iterator.hasNext() && returnCellStyle == null) {
currentCellStyle = iterator.next();

if (currentCellStyle.getAlignment() != styleToFind.getAlignment()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getHidden() != styleToFind.getHidden()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getLocked() != styleToFind.getLocked()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getWrapText() != styleToFind.getWrapText()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getBorderBottom() != styleToFind.getBorderBottom()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getBorderLeft() != styleToFind.getBorderLeft()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getBorderRight() != styleToFind.getBorderRight()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getBorderTop() != styleToFind.getBorderTop()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getBottomBorderColor() != styleToFind.getBottomBorderColor()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getFillBackgroundColor() != styleToFind.getFillBackgroundColor()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getFillForegroundColor() != styleToFind.getFillForegroundColor()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getFillPattern() != styleToFind.getFillPattern()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getIndention() != styleToFind.getIndention()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getLeftBorderColor() != styleToFind.getLeftBorderColor()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getRightBorderColor() != styleToFind.getRightBorderColor()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getRotation() != styleToFind.getRotation()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getTopBorderColor() != styleToFind.getTopBorderColor()) {
continue;
}
if (currentCellStyle.getVerticalAlignment() != styleToFind.getVerticalAlignment()) {
continue;
}

oldFont = oldCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getFontAt(oldCell.getCellStyle().getFontIndex());
newFont = newCell.getSheet().getWorkbook().getFontAt(currentCellStyle.getFontIndex());

if (newFont.getBoldweight() == oldFont.getBoldweight()) {
continue;
}
if (newFont.getColor() == oldFont.getColor()) {
continue;
}
if (newFont.getFontHeight() == oldFont.getFontHeight()) {
continue;
}
if (newFont.getFontName() == oldFont.getFontName()) {
continue;
}
if (newFont.getItalic() == oldFont.getItalic()) {
continue;
}
if (newFont.getStrikeout() == oldFont.getStrikeout()) {
continue;
}
if (newFont.getTypeOffset() == oldFont.getTypeOffset()) {
continue;
}
if (newFont.getUnderline() == oldFont.getUnderline()) {
continue;
}
if (newFont.getCharSet() == oldFont.getCharSet()) {
continue;
}
if (oldCell.getCellStyle().getDataFormatString().equals(currentCellStyle.getDataFormatString())) {
continue;
}

returnCellStyle = currentCellStyle;
}
return returnCellStyle;
}

private static void copySheetSettings(Sheet newSheet, Sheet sheetToCopy) {

newSheet.setAutobreaks(sheetToCopy.getAutobreaks());
newSheet.setDefaultColumnWidth(sheetToCopy.getDefaultColumnWidth());
newSheet.setDefaultRowHeight(sheetToCopy.getDefaultRowHeight());
newSheet.setDefaultRowHeightInPoints(sheetToCopy.getDefaultRowHeightInPoints());
newSheet.setDisplayGuts(sheetToCopy.getDisplayGuts());
newSheet.setFitToPage(sheetToCopy.getFitToPage());

newSheet.setForceFormulaRecalculation(sheetToCopy.getForceFormulaRecalculation());

PrintSetup sheetToCopyPrintSetup = sheetToCopy.getPrintSetup();
PrintSetup newSheetPrintSetup = newSheet.getPrintSetup();

newSheetPrintSetup.setPaperSize(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getPaperSize());
newSheetPrintSetup.setScale(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getScale());
newSheetPrintSetup.setPageStart(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getPageStart());
newSheetPrintSetup.setFitWidth(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getFitWidth());
newSheetPrintSetup.setFitHeight(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getFitHeight());
newSheetPrintSetup.setLeftToRight(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getLeftToRight());
newSheetPrintSetup.setLandscape(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getLandscape());
newSheetPrintSetup.setValidSettings(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getValidSettings());
newSheetPrintSetup.setNoColor(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getNoColor());
newSheetPrintSetup.setDraft(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getDraft());
newSheetPrintSetup.setNotes(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getNotes());
newSheetPrintSetup.setNoOrientation(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getNoOrientation());
newSheetPrintSetup.setUsePage(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getUsePage());
newSheetPrintSetup.setHResolution(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getHResolution());
newSheetPrintSetup.setVResolution(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getVResolution());
newSheetPrintSetup.setHeaderMargin(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getHeaderMargin());
newSheetPrintSetup.setFooterMargin(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getFooterMargin());
newSheetPrintSetup.setCopies(sheetToCopyPrintSetup.getCopies());

Header sheetToCopyHeader = sheetToCopy.getHeader();
Header newSheetHeader = newSheet.getHeader();
newSheetHeader.setCenter(sheetToCopyHeader.getCenter());
newSheetHeader.setLeft(sheetToCopyHeader.getLeft());
newSheetHeader.setRight(sheetToCopyHeader.getRight());

Footer sheetToCopyFooter = sheetToCopy.getFooter();
Footer newSheetFooter = newSheet.getFooter();
newSheetFooter.setCenter(sheetToCopyFooter.getCenter());
newSheetFooter.setLeft(sheetToCopyFooter.getLeft());
newSheetFooter.setRight(sheetToCopyFooter.getRight());

newSheet.setHorizontallyCenter(sheetToCopy.getHorizontallyCenter());
newSheet.setMargin(Sheet.LeftMargin, sheetToCopy.getMargin(Sheet.LeftMargin));
newSheet.setMargin(Sheet.RightMargin, sheetToCopy.getMargin(Sheet.RightMargin));
newSheet.setMargin(Sheet.TopMargin, sheetToCopy.getMargin(Sheet.TopMargin));
newSheet.setMargin(Sheet.BottomMargin, sheetToCopy.getMargin(Sheet.BottomMargin));

newSheet.setPrintGridlines(sheetToCopy.isPrintGridlines());
newSheet.setRowSumsBelow(sheetToCopy.getRowSumsBelow());
newSheet.setRowSumsRight(sheetToCopy.getRowSumsRight());
newSheet.setVerticallyCenter(sheetToCopy.getVerticallyCenter());
newSheet.setDisplayFormulas(sheetToCopy.isDisplayFormulas());
newSheet.setDisplayGridlines(sheetToCopy.isDisplayGridlines());
newSheet.setDisplayRowColHeadings(sheetToCopy.isDisplayRowColHeadings());
newSheet.setDisplayZeros(sheetToCopy.isDisplayZeros());
newSheet.setPrintGridlines(sheetToCopy.isPrintGridlines());
newSheet.setRightToLeft(sheetToCopy.isRightToLeft());
newSheet.setZoom(1, 1);
copyPrintTitle(newSheet, sheetToCopy);
}

private static void copyPrintTitle(Sheet newSheet, Sheet sheetToCopy) {
int nbNames = sheetToCopy.getWorkbook().getNumberOfNames();
Name name = null;
String formula = null;

String part1S = null;
String part2S = null;
String formS = null;
String formF = null;
String part1F = null;
String part2F = null;
int rowB = -1;
int rowE = -1;
int colB = -1;
int colE = -1;

for (int i = 0; i < nbNames; i++) {
name = sheetToCopy.getWorkbook().getNameAt(i);
if (name.getSheetIndex() == sheetToCopy.getWorkbook().getSheetIndex(sheetToCopy)) {
if (name.getNameName().equals("Print_Titles")
    || name.getNameName().equals(XSSFName.BUILTIN_PRINT_TITLE)) {
formula = name.getRefersToFormula();
int indexComma = formula.indexOf(",");
if (indexComma == -1) {
    indexComma = formula.indexOf(";");
}
String firstPart = null;
;
String secondPart = null;
if (indexComma == -1) {
    firstPart = formula;
} else {
    firstPart = formula.substring(0, indexComma);
    secondPart = formula.substring(indexComma + 1);
}

formF = firstPart.substring(firstPart.indexOf("!") + 1);
part1F = formF.substring(0, formF.indexOf(":"));
part2F = formF.substring(formF.indexOf(":") + 1);

if (secondPart != null) {
    formS = secondPart.substring(secondPart.indexOf("!") + 1);
    part1S = formS.substring(0, formS.indexOf(":"));
    part2S = formS.substring(formS.indexOf(":") + 1);
}

rowB = -1;
rowE = -1;
colB = -1;
colE = -1;
String rowBs, rowEs, colBs, colEs;
if (part1F.lastIndexOf("$") != part1F.indexOf("$")) {
    rowBs = part1F.substring(part1F.lastIndexOf("$") + 1, part1F.length());
    rowEs = part2F.substring(part2F.lastIndexOf("$") + 1, part2F.length());
    rowB = Integer.parseInt(rowBs);
    rowE = Integer.parseInt(rowEs);
    if (secondPart != null) {
        colBs = part1S.substring(part1S.lastIndexOf("$") + 1, part1S.length());
        colEs = part2S.substring(part2S.lastIndexOf("$") + 1, part2S.length());
        colB = CellReference.convertColStringToIndex(colBs);// CExportExcelHelperPoi.convertColumnLetterToInt(colBs);
        colE = CellReference.convertColStringToIndex(colEs);// CExportExcelHelperPoi.convertColumnLetterToInt(colEs);
    }
} else {
    colBs = part1F.substring(part1F.lastIndexOf("$") + 1, part1F.length());
    colEs = part2F.substring(part2F.lastIndexOf("$") + 1, part2F.length());
    colB = CellReference.convertColStringToIndex(colBs);// CExportExcelHelperPoi.convertColumnLetterToInt(colBs);
    colE = CellReference.convertColStringToIndex(colEs);// CExportExcelHelperPoi.convertColumnLetterToInt(colEs);

    if (secondPart != null) {
        rowBs = part1S.substring(part1S.lastIndexOf("$") + 1, part1S.length());
        rowEs = part2S.substring(part2S.lastIndexOf("$") + 1, part2S.length());
        rowB = Integer.parseInt(rowBs);
        rowE = Integer.parseInt(rowEs);
    }
}

newSheet.getWorkbook().setRepeatingRowsAndColumns(newSheet.getWorkbook().getSheetIndex(newSheet),
        colB, colE, rowB - 1, rowE - 1);
}
}
}
}
}
```

Comment: These long code examples are usually posted to codereview instead of stackoverflow. A moderator may move this post. I indented your code with http://www.tutorialspoint.com/online_java_formatter.htm so that it's readable. The formatted code is here: http://pastebin.com/KqHbRdDC

Comment: @IceArdor The code doesn't work, therefore it's off-topic on [CodeReview.SE]. ("And I used code here(it doesn't work)")

Comment: @IceArdor length of the post has no bearing whatsoever on the topicality of the question on Code Review. If this question is off-topic, flag or vote to close it as such, please don't move posts you don't want to see over to other sites just because you don't want to see them here.

Comment: Please read: [mcve] and [ask]. As it stands it's not clear what the problem is. Questions asking "why isn't my code working" need a clear problem statement.

Comment: Thank you so much, I'm a newbie in here and my english is not verry well,sorry about that

Comment: As per the [POI FAQ, don't mix jars between versions!](http://poi.apache.org/faq.html#faq-N10204)

Comment: I have changed it, but it still doesn't work, i use apache poi 3.14 and poi-ooxml-3.14. And what do I need to insert sheet(just image) with extension .xls to another workbook but still keep this format